# Search for a newline charactor or CR/LF characters

Tags: c

I am searching a string and the string could contain a newline or a CRLF. I increment the pointer to search through each character. I have converted the hex to decimal. However, as I am looking for a single char, I am not sure this would be the best way to do this.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
   /*
      0x0a (ASCII newline)
      0x0d (ASCII carriage return)
      CRLF (0x0d0a)
    */

    while(*search != '\0') {
        /* Seach for a newline */
        if(*search == 10) {
            printf("\nnewline Found\n");
        }

        /* Search for a CRLF */
        if(*search == 3338) {
            printf("\nCRLF Found\n");
        }

        search++;
    }
```

I'm compiling with gcc 4.6.2 in C89-mode.

Comment: Here's the Q&A with some details on Japanese encodings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724247/newline-control-characters-in-multi-byte-character-sets?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRLF is two characters: CR, and LF. You need to match them both individually, not together as you've done with `3338` (I think: where did you get that number?) Also, use the character constants: `'\0'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, it will make your code clearer.

```
/*
  0x0a (ASCII newline)
  0x0d (ASCII carriage return)
  CRLF (0x0d0a)
*/

while(*search != '\0') {
    /* Seach for a newline */
    if(*search == '\n') {
        printf("\nnewline Found\n");
        search++;
    }

    /* Search for a CR or a CRLF */
    if(*search == '\r') {
        // OK, we found a CR, is it followed by a LF?
        if(*(search + 1) == '\n') {
            // Yes, it is, thus, it is a CRLF
            printf("\nCRLF Found\n");
            search += 2; // Note the 2! CRLF is 2 characters!
        }
        else {
            // No, just a lonely CR, forever alone.
            printf("\nCarriage return found\n");
            search++;
        }
    }
}
```

As another poster suggests, you can also use the `strchr` and `strstr` functions, and take the minimum valid result from them. (It'll be like 3 lines of code.)

Comment: The check `*(search + 1) != '\0'` is unnecessary in the inner `if` statement, when you're also checking if `*(search + 1) == '\n'`.

Comment: @AsusCBloke: You're absolutely right — edited. Being too careful with my bounds checking…

Comment: `'\n'` isn't just clearer, it's more correct - this code will now work on EBCDIC systems! (...that also happen to use CRLF for their line endings...)

Answer (score 2):

Look up the `strchr` and `strstr` functions. They've been made for this.

But CRLF is not one character, that's two characters. To locate that, search for '\n' and check the previous character.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply modify your code to:

```
for(; *search != '\0'; search++) {
    /* Seach for a newline */
    if(*search == '\n') {
        printf("\nnewline Found\n");
    }
    /* Search for a CRLF */
    else if(*search == '\r' && *(search + 1) == '\n') {
        printf("\nCRLF Found\n");
        search++; /* search will be incremented twice (bit hacky?) */
    }
}
```

Short-circuiting in the `if` statement will prevent `(search + 1)` being dereferenced if `*search` is not `'\r'`, so that won't cause you to go past the bounds of the string if `*search` turns out to be `'0'`.

`*search == 3338` in your previous code example isn't going to work if `search` is a `char*`/`char[]`, since a *single* `char` can only represent 256 different values and CRLF is a sequence of 2 bytes (2 `char`s).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use `strstr()` and **not** to use `strchr()`, as the latter  is not multi-byte character save (per definition).

Also the two methods `strspn()`, `strcspn()` could help.

Answer (score 0):

personally i'm doing it like this for the time being with the test stub i'm using ~

..mainly because I just get to use the modulo operator :D

```
int count(char *s) {
    char *p = s; 
    int i = 0;         
    while (*p) { 
        if (*p == '\r' || *p == '\n') { 
            i++;
        }
        p++; 
    }        
    if (i % 2 != 0) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", "\n\x1b[31mgooby pls?\x1b[0m\n");
            dosomething;  
    }
    return i / 2; 
}
```