# How to read FastAPI UploadFile as text one line at a time

Tags: python, post, fastapi

I am making a REST API using FastAPI and Python.  For example here is an api that takes an uploaded file, and returns an array that with the length of each line.

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/api/upload1')
async def post_a_file(file: UploadFile):    
    result = []
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(file.file, encoding='utf-8')
    while True:
        s = f.readline()
        if not s: break
        result.append(len(s))
    return result
```

However this fails with error...

```
f = io.TextIOWrapper(file.file, encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

If i change to

```
    f = file.file
    while True:
        s = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

then it works, but that is <del>stupid</del>, because reading a "line" of bytes doesn't make sense.

What is the **right** way to do this?

**EDIT:** As I learned (see comments) it is *not wrong* to read a "line" of bytes, because the line break characters (either 0x0A or 0x0D0A) are the same in all character sets.

Comment: You can iterate over file line by line `result = [len(line) for line in file.file]` but if file opened in binary mode *(which seems to be the case)* you will get each line as `bytes` which you should `.decode()` if you want to work with string.

Comment: It's not really _stupid_ per se either, since you're explicitly asking "split my binary data by values that matches what we use to express a new line" when calling `readline`; the concept of a "line" can still have meaning without decoding the content of that line.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) helpful

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at [`bytes.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines)

Comment: @MatsLindh I should have said "naive". The naive approach would be to split on 0x0A.  However without decoding it is impossible to tell if the 0x0A is a single byte character (line feed) or part of a larger multibyte character (which is not a line feed).  Or is there some rule in UTF-8 that 0x0A can never be ever part of a multibyte character?

Comment: [There is such a rule - anything up to 0x7F will never appear in a multibyte UTF-8 codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding). The most significant bit is _always_ set for each byte in a multi-byte UTF-8 codepoint. You could argue that there might be encodings where this is not true, but actually most have some sort of variant of the same thing (including SHIFT-JIS where [anything below 0x20 won't appear in multi-byte encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724247/newline-control-characters-in-multi-byte-character-sets)). Newlines are simply ingrained in low level charsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you faced that `UploadFile` object returned from fastapi is file like object but doesn't have the same attributes of file object that's why you see that error.

so the right approach is to use `io.TextIOWrapper` as you did to provide the right encoding and cause you use `TextIOWrapper` you should use `async for` loop instead of `while True`

This is the updated code with the right approach

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, UploadFile
import io

router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/api/upload1')
async def post_a_file(file: UploadFile):
    result = []
    async with file.file as f:
        async for line in io.TextIOWrapper(f, encoding='utf-8'):
            result.append(len(line))
    return result
```

- `async with` used for handling opening and closing the file.
- `async for` used for iteating the file line by line and appending them in result list.

I hope this helps.